# Add one hour from _GET

Tags: php, strtotime

I'm using `date('H', strtotime($_GET['h'].' +1 hour'))` at the moment (`$_GET['h']` contains the hour I'm getting from the URL, i.e. 20 as in 20:00) but it only prints `01` when it should print `21`. I want to get this hour and add one hour to it so 20 will be 21 and so on.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Better ways, but: http://ideone.com/1ICO8a == 21

Comment: Thanks but John's answer was better :)

Comment: Mine wasn't an answer, it was your question and code!  So I don't see how you get `01` from your code and stated input. But agree about John's code ;)

Comment: Oh. Ok. I didn't see your question mark in your comment so I though it was an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$time = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', '20:00');
$time->modify('+1 hour');
echo $time->format('H:i');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/kjlZ42)

Comment: Many thanks! That did it :) I'll accept your answer as soon as I can.

Comment: +1 for use of DateTime, which should be used in almost any example of basic data manipulation in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can add seconds to the timestamp to do this:

```
date('H',mktime($_GET['h']) + 60 * 60)
```

Since the timestamp must be in seconds, the first 60 * 60 gets the hour in seconds. The second one adds an hour's worth of seconds to the timestamp.

Comment: This method avoids the overhead of instantiating a date object just to get the hour, but sacrifices readability.

Comment: Thanks but your code prints only `02` no mater what the hour is set to :/ Sorry for my bad English

Comment: You are right, strtotime doesn't work there. Updated the answer to use mktime() instead.