# How to add 11 hours to time stored as string

Tags: php, date, date-math

I have a date and timestamp in HL7 format : 201402181659

That represents 2014 02 18 at 16:59

it's offset by +11:00 hours so I need to be able to add 11 hours to the date/time. Any ideas?

Comment: Convert it to a date object and then add the desired amount of hours, then convert it back to the format you like.

Comment: See [`this answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21998936/) and change it to `11` also consult http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](https://www.php.net/datetime.createfromformat) to parse the string and then [`DateTime::modify()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) to add 11 hours to it:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHis', '201402181659');
$date->modify('+11 hours');
echo $date->format('YmdHis');
```

You can also use [`DateTime::add()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) with [`DateInterval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) to add the 11 hours:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHis', '201402181659');
$date->add(new DateInterval('PT11H'));
echo $date->format('YmdHis');
```

Comment: I based my comment on your answer actually John ;-) figured it would help the OP.

Comment: ..at the same time I was adding the example using `DateTime::add()` just as you suggested :)

Comment: Tried the code from John and get: Call to a member function modify() on a non-object    If I comment that line out I then get:   Call to a member function format() on a non-object      The $date is a string. Is that the problem?

Comment: Try changing `YmdHis` to `YmdHi`